# How to restart/resume copydb() in mongodb after interruption?

Tags: mongodb, copy, database

The mongodb was interrupted when doing a copyDb() command. When I want to restart I get:

```
db.runCommand( { copydb: 1, fromhost: "<ip>", fromdb: "<collection>", todb: "<db>", slaveOk: true } );
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "failed to create collection \"<db>.<collection>\": collection already exists"
}
```

Is there a way to resume the copy of a DB after an interruption or do I need to drop the database and start from the beginning? (Not a good option as the copy requires ~10 days and already ran 2 days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no built-in way to resume a `copydb` operation, it essentially requires/assumes 100% availability at both ends during the operation. To re-use the `copydb` command, you will have to drop the destination database and re-start the copy from scratch.

Besides coding something yourself (which is always an option), the only tool I know of that gives something close to a resume is [hydra](https://github.com/dropbox/hydra), and in that case the functionality is only intended to be used as a way to pick up small numbers of stragglers from a nearly complete copy.

The other potential option would be to use [MMS Backup](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/#backup-with-mms) (full disclosure: I currently work for MongoDB, which offers MMS Backup as a paid-for service), which will create regular snapshots of the data for a backed up database, including indexes.  These snapshots can then be used to restore to other nodes with a simple download/transfer rather than relying on a copy command.